# Can't get D3 particles example to work?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm looking at Mike Bostock's [particles example](http://bl.ocks.org/d/1062544/) for D3.js.

I have copied and pasted the code locally, without changing anything at all. I'm running the code using SimpleHTTPServer, so there shouldn't be any security issues to do with running locally.

Whenever I mouseover the body, I see the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'mouse'
```

Does anyone know what might be going on? Can anyone get it to work locally?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you actually hardcopied the entire referenced library? It could be an inter-domain referencing issue. Did you do a reference directly to `http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js?1.25.0` ? it could be, that this is not possible from outside that domain.

Comment: Figured it out - I was referring to version 3 of D3, not the older version linked above. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

There's a way to fix the code, so that you can reference the latest release of D3 at http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js

The error you're getting is caused by the line
var m = d3.svg.mouse(this);
Change it to
var m = d3.mouse(this);
and you should be fine.

See the release notes here, on the changes from D3 v2 to v3:
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Upgrading-to-3.0

Specifically:

"SVG:  The aliases d3.svg.mouse and d3.svg.touches have been removed; use d3.mouse and d3.touches instead. These methods are identical, and were moved in an earlier minor release that added support for HTML as well as SVG elements."